# Azure Integrate Source Control Multiple Projects

Tags: git, azure

I have a git repository with two visual studio projects. When azure tries deploying the code it fails with following error:

> Unable to determine which solution file to build. D:\home\site\repository\project1.sln, D:\home\site\repository\project2.sln

How do i let Azure know which project to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your git repo create a **.deployment** file. Add the following:

```
[config]
project = project\project1.csproj
```